# Changed Wordress Address URL Accidently

Tags: login, urls

Accidently, I have changed my wordpress address url from my dashboard. Now I am not able to sign in to get it changed. This is where I have installed wordpress - http://www.abc.com/folder, but accidently, I changed the wordpress address URL to http://www.abc.com

Please help me...

Comment: There is an extensive explanation at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest fix is [to edit `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php) to define two constants. (s)FTP into your site, or use a host supplied file manager, and add:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.abc.com/folder' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://www.abc.com/folder' );
```

Those will be used instead of the information in the database. That will get your site up and running again. You won't be able to edit the URLs from the back-end so long as that is in place but the site should run just fine. I have even seen argument that you get a slight performance increase but have never tried to verify that claim.

Once the site is up, you can get into the database and fix the incorrect values if you'd like. [There are instructions in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database) that really boil down to:

1. Backup
2. Open your database via PhpMyAdmin, or similar tool
3. Navigate to the `*_options` table
4. Edit the value for key 'siteurl'
5. Edit the value for key 'home'

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on the Codex that explains how to fix this in great detail:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle this is to take the script from https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases , unzip it and copy the PHP file into your WP folder, call it with the direct URL - http://www.abc.com/folder/customnameofscript.php and do the following:

- First, **PLEASE CREATE A BACKUP OF YOUR DATABASE**, just in case!
- Replace **http://www.abc.com** with **http://www.abc.com/folder**
- Replace **http://www.abc.com/folder/folder** with **http://www.abc.com/folder** (because you may have references to previous URLs and you need to fix those)
- If you are using just the domain name without **http://**, make sure to replace any **@www.abc.com/folder** with **@www.abc.com** to fix email addresses

---

Another option would be to read the thread at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-access-dashboard-accidentally-changed-url and all additional links in there and handle it on your own from the database. Again, remember to **CREATE A BACKUP OF YOUR DATABASE** first!

Comment: Thanks... I will try this.. Lets hope this will work... :)